# How to modify PHP password connection to the database?

Tags: php

I have only access to a source code (`connect.php`) from previous developer as

```
<?php $_F=__FILE__;$_X='Pz48P3BocA0KNG40X3M1dCgnZDRzcGwxeV81cnIycnMnLCdPZmYnKTsNCiRjMm4gPSBteXNxbF9jMm5uNWN0KCJsMmMxbGgyc3QiLCJyMjJ0IiwibW0xYWFhOSIpOw0KbXlzcWxfczVsNWN0X2RiKCJtNHRyMSIsICRjMm4pOw0KNGYgKCEkYzJuKQ0KICB7DQogIGQ0NSgnSzJuNWtzNCBnMWcxbCAhOiAnIC4gbXlzcWxfNXJyMnIoKSk7DQogIH0NCj8+';eval(base64_decode('JF9YPWJhc2U2NF9kZWNvZGUoJF9YKTskX1g9c3RydHIoJF9YLCcxMjM0NTZhb3VpZScsJ2FvdWllMTIzNDU2Jyk7JF9SPWVyZWdfcmVwbGFjZSgnX19GSUxFX18nLCInIi4kX0YuIiciLCRfWCk7ZXZhbCgkX1IpOyRfUj0wOyRfWD0wOw=='));?>
```

Then I googled there's tool to decode the above `encrypted` text which gives me

```
?><?php
ini_set('display_errors','Off');
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","mma2229");
mysql_select_db("mitra", $con);
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Koneksi gagal !: ' . mysql_error());
  }
?>
```

All I need is just to change the password (example to "123") but I do not know where to start.

How can I set the my `connect.php` with my new password ?

Comment: go to your database management system panel and change password there and then update it here

Comment: this is a root password and my mysql is used by multiple applications. Changing the password will break the other connections.

Comment: then create another user in your database management system.. do you use phpmyadmin as your system software for database?

Comment: Lets say I have a new user and password. How do I fit them to the source code in the `connect.php` ? How do I encrypt them just like the above example ?

Comment: you don't need to encrypt your password.. because your password isn't going to visible to anyone. If you do so, there will no benefit for this you will have i believe

Comment: A general hint: a "php developer" delivering code in such a form should not be trusted. If I were you I would dump all that code and start from scratch or using other examples. A programmer who relies on such way to "protect" database credentials most likely also has other areas where he propagates more then questionable "solutions".

Comment: @arkascha. I thought the reason he did what he did is to secure the credentials. Is not it ?

Comment: That probably was the reason, which I already stated. But it makes no sense at all. This is _not_ a protection, it is obfuscation which does not add security. It generates a false sense of security. It demonstrates a fundamental miss understanding of security aspects.

Comment: what is the value of $_F=__FILE__; ?

Comment: As long as the script is outside of the document root tree, there is no risk for exposing the credentials. And even if it is inside, when the web server is configured properly there is no risk either.

Comment: How did you decrypt the encrypted php text to give you the code?

Comment: Just delete the previous developers base64 encoded mess, and use the decoded php and change the password.

No reason to base64 encode this stuff.

Comment: @Webdev Just look at the code given, it is base64 encoded twice.

Comment: To add to what @Boli commented , you can create new php code with tne new password and then base64 encode it twice and include it in your code

Comment: Its not simply encoded twice. The next encoded eval string is: $_X=base64_decode($_X);
$_X=strtr($_X,'123456aouie','aouie123456');
$_R=ereg_replace('__FILE__',"'".$_F."'",$_X);
eval($_R);
$_R=0;
$_X=0;

But this does not matter - just delete the entire code and use the none encoded mysql connect code with your new password. :)

Comment: I have never used PHP before. The idea is to get it up and running so I can see the application on my laptop. Thank you all for the insights :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace the previous delevopers code:

```
<?php $_F=__FILE__;$_X='Pz48P3BocA0KNG40X3M1dCgnZDRzcGwxeV81cnIycnMnLCdPZmYnKTsNCiRjMm4gPSBteXNxbF9jMm5uNWN0KCJsMmMxbGgyc3QiLCJyMjJ0IiwibW0xYWFhOSIpOw0KbXlzcWxfczVsNWN0X2RiKCJtNHRyMSIsICRjMm4pOw0KNGYgKCEkYzJuKQ0KICB7DQogIGQ0NSgnSzJuNWtzNCBnMWcxbCAhOiAnIC4gbXlzcWxfNXJyMnIoKSk7DQogIH0NCj8+';eval(base64_decode('JF9YPWJhc2U2NF9kZWNvZGUoJF9YKTskX1g9c3RydHIoJF9YLCcxMjM0NTZhb3VpZScsJ2FvdWllMTIzNDU2Jyk7JF9SPWVyZWdfcmVwbGFjZSgnX19GSUxFX18nLCInIi4kX0YuIiciLCRfWCk7ZXZhbCgkX1IpOyRfUj0wOyRfWD0wOw=='));?>
```

With:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors','Off');
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","123"); // put your new password instead of 123
mysql_select_db("mitra", $con);
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Koneksi gagal !: ' . mysql_error());
  }
?>
```

Comment: @abiieez And don't forget to replace `mysql_*` with either `mysqli` or `PDO`.

Answer (score 0):

In your phpMyAdmin panel write query like this:

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = password('mynewpass')
```

**Setting new user / change password in view**

If you want to do it with clicking, go to phpMyAdmin, click on the top Users -> Edit Privileges and there you can change a password. In this view you can also add new user which can be used in your PHP code.